# Script Reference in Unity

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm creating a game that have multiples references to scripts, one to another.

For exemple:

1. Controller script
2. SomeBehavior script
3. GUI script

My doubt enter when I can do two different things:

1. In SomeBehavior access/edit GUI variable/function that I whant... Like: 
   1.1. variable = GameObject.Find("GuiTag").GetComponent< GUI script >(); 
     variable.score.... and go on...
2. In SomeBehavior access/edit GUI variable/function by Controller.gui (gui a public variable on controller script)... Centralization all the base scripts to one, in that way, having less variables in the scripts, less memory (perraps)...
    
   2.1. variable = GameObject.Find("ControllerTag").GetComponent< Controller script >(); 
     variable.gui.score....

Which one is better?

Comment: Benchmark and test.  You should store results of `GameObject.Find` if you'll use them again, `Find` is a spendy call.  As far as memory goes... you should probably read up on C#'s reference types.  "Less variables in the scripts" has little-to-no relation to memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the Scripts that you will only have one of you can set a public static variable in that class with a public get and private set.  On the Start or Awake function you set that variable to this and then you can access that script easily from any other scripts.